# Salesforce URL Formula Field Issue - Seems simple to fix, but who knows

Tags: formula, formula-field, fields

I'm working on a Salesforce coding issue. Let me preface this by saying I'm not a developer or Salesforce expert.  But I've identified an issue, that can be resolved if we can figure out how to
recode this.

Data Type: Formula(Text)

```
IF (Fulfillment_Submission_Form_URL__c <> "" && CONTAINS(Fulfillment_Submission_Form_URL__c, "qualtrics"),
    
     Fulfillment_Submission_Form_URL__c &
    
     (IF (CONTAINS(Fulfillment_Submission_Form_URL__c,"?SID="), "&", "?")) &
    
     (IF (CONTAINS(TEXT(Type__c), "Site Visit"),
     "ContactId="&Statement_of_Work__r.Contractor_Contact__c&
     "&CoachType="&SUBSTITUTE(Statement_of_Work__r.Work_Type__r.Name," ","%20")&
     "&CoachName="&SUBSTITUTE(Statement_of_Work__r.Contractor_Name__c," ","%20")&
     "&InitPartId="&Initiative_Participation__r.Id&
     "&InstitutionName="&substitute(substitute(SUBSTITUTE(Institution_Name__c," ","%20"),")",""),"(","")&
     "&AccountId="&Initiative_Participation__r.Participating_Institution__r.Id&
     "&TodaysDate="&TEXT(TODAY())&
     "&SOWLineItemId="&Id&
     "&LeaderCollege="&Initiative_Participation__r.ATD_Leader_College_Status__c&
     "&SVRCompleted="&TEXT(Count_of_Site_Visit_Fulfillments__c)&
     "&SVRRequired="&TEXT(Number_of_Work_Units_Allocated__c),
    
     IF (CONTAINS(TEXT(Type__c), "Feedback"),
     "InitPartId="&Initiative_Participation__r.Id&
     "&SOWLineItemId="&Id&
     "&ReportYear="&Statement_of_Work__r.SOW_Year__c&
     "&UserId="&Contractor_User_Id__c&
     "&InstitutionName="&substitute(substitute(SUBSTITUTE(Institution_Name__c," ","%20"),")",""),"(",""),
     "")
     ))
    
     ,"")
```

The code is supposed to take a standard URL provided by a third party system we integrate with example:  https://www.REDACTED.com/jfe/form/SV_3JjFpMRH8XdunTT?

And add parameters ex:  https://www.REDACTED.com/jfe/form/SV_3JjFpMRH8XdunTT?ContactId=003U0000009FT0I&CoachType=ABC%20Leadership%20Coach&CoachName=Kaul%20(Coach)%20Christ&InitPartId=a0l0B00001KUdaA&InstitutionName=Marymount%20State%20Community%20College%20TN&AccountId=0010B00001n7cT5&TodaysDate=2022-08-24&SOWLineItemId=a1d4O00000FUgN1&LeaderCollege=&SVRCompleted=1&SVRRequired=1

The problem is the CoachName parameter.  The issue is some coach names by way of the way we do business might be entered/listed as:   "John (Coach) Doe".

The (Coach) part of the name is creating an issue.

Issue is:  The new link with parameters gets sent in reports, and emails to staff.  They're supposed to click the link and complete their surveys.  The problem is "(Coach)" portion is where the "clickable" link fails to be recognized as a hyperlink.  So the users sees all the text of the hyperlink but only half is clickable.

[image: Broken Link/Half Clickable]

Copy and pasting the link in its entirety and pasting it in a browser works, however these are non-technical end users we can't expect them to know or remember that.

How can we tweak the code such that even though Coach Name sometimes has coaches who entered their name as  "John (Coach) Doe" less the quotation marks to not break the new link with parameters by making the link half clickable (it is a hyperlink up until CoachName=).

I hope that makes sense.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameters need to be properly URL-encoded. That means percent-encoding most special characters (&, ", %, etc). As such, a formula field is a really terrible way to accomplish this. Instead, you can make it a Custom Link (to put in the body) or a Custom Button (to place it in the top menu). See this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_customization/lex_customization_buttons_links) for more details. You will want to build this with [URLFOR](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_urlfor.htm&type=5) and/or [URLENCODE](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_urlencode.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thank you.  That might be a bit over my head.  If the previous commenters suggestion doesn't work I will have my dev try your suggestion when he returns from vacation.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of pointers that I think can help you out here:

- Your formula constructs a URL and then returns that, relying on the "linkify" algorithm on the front end to turn it into something clickable. Instead of simply returning the result of your URL, your formula can wrap the URL in a HYPERLINK() function and return that. You can use it like this:

```
HYPERLINK(
 /* THIS IS WHERE YOUR CURRENT FORMULA LOGIC GOES */,
 "Label for the clickable link"
)
```

- You are replacing spaces with `%20` with a `SUBSTITUTE()` function, but there are other characters that need to be encoded when being passed as a value in a URL's querystring. This is a tough one because Formula Fields don't support the formula function that would make this easy (`URLENCODE()`). If you can build this as a URL button instead of a Formula Field, you can handle this better by replacing those `SUBSTITUTE()` functions with `URLENCODE()`. Something like this:

```
"&CoachName="&URLENCODE(Statement_of_Work__r.Contractor_Name__c)&
```

Note that if you use a URL Button, you won't need the HYPERLINK() function

Comment: Thank you!  The wrapping in hyperlink passed the syntax test so that's a great news!  I'm waiting for my team to test.  Fingers crossed!!  I feel like this could be just what we need.  Keep you posted!